Edit without modifiers while previewing with modifiers
Editing an object which has a subsurf modifier. I have the modifier set to not be visible in edit mode, however I would like it to be visible in a separate 3d viewport while I'm editing it. Is this possible?

Hello and welcome. I don't think it's possible.

Just like @HarryMcKenzie said, it is not possible. The modifier only has options for the specific modes, not for different editor windows. Just like you cannot have an object in Edit Mode in one viewport window and at the same time in Object Mode in a different viewport.

Oh well. Thank you both!

Yes, it's possible as shown in the attached screenshot.

The steps are as follows:

Create a linked duplicate of the object by running Object > Duplicate Linked. This creates a new object that shares the object data of the original which means Edit Mode changes will affect both at the same time.
Place the linked duplicate in a new collection. The original object should be in its own collection as well.
Add the Subdivision Surface modifier to the original and the linked duplicate if they don't already have it. Note that the modifiers are attached to the object, so each can have its own unique settings and/or have its own list of modifiers.
Right now, the objects will be on top of each other in the same 3D Viewport. Create a new 3D Viewport by running View > Area > Vertical Split.
To show only one object in each 3D Viewport, check Local Collections in the Collections panel under the View tab in the Sidebar in both 3D Viewports. Also, enable only one of the collections such that each 3D Viewport displays one or the other of the two objects' collections.
Disable Edit Mode on the Subdivision Surface modifier of the original object, the object you will edit.

Now, if you select and edit the original, you'll see the edits affecting the linked duplicate, since they share the object data. You'll see only one object in each 3D Viewport thanks to the 3D Viewport Local Collections setting. You can customize the modifiers of each object independently, since the modifier list is stored at the object level.

Thank you! I was not aware of local collections. Amazing feature.

You're welcome!
